# Flutter container pop up how can I do like in the gif? What type of widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I would like something similar to this in Flutter. How can I do this effect? What is the widget to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DraggableScrollableSheet](https://youtu.be/Hgw819mL_78) should allow smth like this.

Comment: How can i do to show only when i pressed a container the same of the gif i've insert in the question?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sliding_up_panel` package to get a similar effect.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("SlidingUpPanelExample"),
    ),
    body: SlidingUpPanel(
      panel: Center(
        child: Text("This is the sliding Widget"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("This is the Widget behind the sliding panel"),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Look [here](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) for more.

[image]

Comment: How can i do to show only when i pressed a container the same of the gif i've insert in the question?